# JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough privilege to lock pages in memory

Tags: java, jvm, paging

I wonder how can I reconcile the following error?

> JVM cannot use large page memory because it does not have enough
>   privilege to lock pages in memory

The settings are:

> set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
>   -XX:+UseLargePages -Duser.timezone="GMT" %DEBUG%

This happened on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: This is happening on Windows 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Windows Server 2003 supports large page memory. In order to use it, the administrator must first assign additional privilege to the user who will be running the application:
1.  select Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy 
2.  select Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment 
3.  double click "Lock pages in memory", add users and/or groups 
4.  reboot the machine

Comment: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/largememory.jsp

Only Windows Server 2003 supports that among the windows family. Solaris and Linux support them too.

Comment: how does Large Memory benefit a jvm?   why is it important to lock a process into physical memory?

Answer (score 8):

Googling on the error leads to the [hotspot/src/os/win32/vm/os_win32.cpp](http://xref.jsecurity.net/openjdk-6/langtools/dd/d8f/os__win32_8cpp-source.html) source file in openjdk-6 wich contains the following comment:

```
// Windows large page support is available on Windows 2003. In order to use
// large page memory, the administrator must first assign additional privilege
// to the user:
//   + select Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy
//   + select Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment
//   + double click "Lock pages in memory", add users and/or groups
//   + reboot
// Note the above steps are needed for administrator as well, as administrators
// by default do not have the privilege to lock pages in memory.
//
// Note about Windows 2003: although the API supports committing large page
// memory on a page-by-page basis and VirtualAlloc() returns success under this
// scenario, I found through experiment it only uses large page if the entire
// memory region is reserved and committed in a single VirtualAlloc() call.
// This makes Windows large page support more or less like Solaris ISM, in
// that the entire heap must be committed upfront. This probably will change
// in the future, if so the code below needs to be revisited.
```

If you're using Windows 2003, this might help. If not, I don't have any other suggestion.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-ver15 - Applies to Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 (uses gpedit.msc)

Answer (score 2):

I faced that only set configurations below is not enough:

> Windows large page support is available on Windows 2003. In order to use
>   large page memory, the administrator must first assign additional privilege
>   to the user:
>
> > - select Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy
> > - select Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment
> > - double click "Lock pages in memory", add users and/or groups
> > - reboot
>
> Note the above steps are needed for administrator as well, as administrators
>   by default do not have the privilege to lock pages in memory.

The program who will call the java interpreter (java *program.java*) must be called with administrative rulles. Example: Eclipse, Netbeans, cmd, etc. In Windows made after 2003, you need do settings above, and after you can click with right button to open menu and choose **"run as admnistrator"** on the icon or executable caller program.